# Asynchronously upload file to server and allow user to move another page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload

The title itself may not be clear but let me tell you a scenario. I have a small asp.net mvc application of 4-5 pages. One page is a small form with file upload control. While development we implemented normal FileUpload control and that is posted on page submit. As this application is also accessed by clients that have very low bandwidth connectivity (5 mb files takes 35-40sec). Users also connect via mobile/tablets which has always bandwidth issue.

I want to make the file upload in a different request to the server and if user submits the form then allow him to move another page and file keeps uploading behind the scene. If we allow user to move another page, it wont be possible keep track of earlier request which is uploading file. I thought of other approach like opening a window itself(and hide it) to upload the file from there and close that window when file gets uploaded etc. Please suggest me some other approaches( any best practices) which can suffice the purpose. One more point here that most of users are using old browser (IE9)

Comment: Users also connect via tablets doesn't really fit with your statement that they're using Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: Mobile/tablet users are there but less in number. 80% are desktop users and mostly with IE9 Thanks

Comment: You can write your site as a [single page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). From the browser's perspective, you're still on one page.

Comment: Agreed!! That could be one way but it will require kind of re-write the application (lots of approval, resources :( etc ) and also later may face some browser issues as well (being IE9). Looking for some more options/approaches

Answer (score 0):

You many need to primarily use ASP.NET Web Api and Ajax based on my experience. In your single page, you may dispay the fileupload `div`, and when user chooses a file and click upload button, you can display a smaller div with a simple text inside it saying `File is being loaded... Please wait`. For example, you can display this informational div on the right hand-side. At the same time, you can display the next div with the contents you want to show next (instead of navigation the user to a different page).

This involves using ajax and (preferable) Asp.Net Web Api. If you have some experience with Ajax and Jquery, it should not take too much time to complete this.

I recommend the following resource for uploading file with Ajax and Web Api:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806075/File-Upload-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASP-NET-Web-API

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Its bit similar as @mason suggested.I have already thought of similar n many other approaches.  But here the point is - user should be free to go to any page on the application (here 5 pages) and able to do whatever want to do. So I have to change each page and load it on same form (when user navigates) via ajax so the state of the page gets maintained. As other pages are also heavy actionable pages, it would be further bit tough to handle all this on same page without affecting upload and its tracking. Uploading file via webapi, jquery is not an issue